# Check if a number exists within a range in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, project, php-mongodb

I want to check if a number exists within an range in project and return true and false accordingly.

This is my code

So far i have used `$cond` along with `if` and '$and' to check the number

```
'$project' => 
[
  'mrp' =>
    [
      '$cond' => 
      [
        'if' => 
        [
          '$and' =>
            [
              ['$lte' => ['$mrp', 100]],
              ['$gte' => ['$mrp', 0]]
            ],
           'then' => 'true',
           'else' => 'false'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I would want to return true

Comment: Does not need the `$cond`. Just` `'mrp' => [  '$and' =>    [  ['$lte' => ['$mrp', 100] ], [ '$gte' => ['$mrp', 0] ]  ] ]`. The `$and` and other aggregation comparison operators already return a boolean. You problem BTW was incorrect nesting, but you also just don't need `$cond` here.

Comment: Before submitting pipelines and other data structures, I suggest you use `json_encode()` in order to produce the JSON version of your PHP data structures for printing in debug logging. This allows you to easily compare to the vast amount of JavaScript syntax examples and ensure your PHP data structure is actually correct. Here it was not, and hence the problem. i.e the `else` and `then` are **inside** the `if`, when they should be on the same level.

Comment: thank you for the advice . appreciate it

Comment: and the solution worked . i was unnecessarily complicating it